# How do I add more than one return statement inside a method?

Tags: java, arrays, object, return, return-value

I am trying to return some values of some objects by using `getter` and `setter` method. Now I can't return more than one value inside a single method. In this case, do I need to create different methods for each `return.` If not, how could I solve it?

My code:

```
    package books;

public class BooksObject {
    //variable for book 1

    String name1 = "The brief history of time";
    String isbn1 = "111";
    String[] authName1 = {"S. Hawking", " Hawking's friend"};

//variable for book 2
    String name2 = "100 years of solitude";
    String isbn2 = "222";
    String[] authName2 = {"G. Marquez", "Marquezs friend"};

    //All setters
    public void setBook1(String n_1, String i_1, String[] a_N1) {
        name1 = n_1;
        isbn1 = i_1;

        String[] authName1 = a_N1;
    }

    public void setBook2(String n_2, String i_2, String[] a_N2) {
        name2 = n_2;
        isbn2 = i_2;

        String[] authName2 = a_N2;
    }

    //All getters method
    public String getBook1() {
        return name1;

        //return isbn1; //shows error
        //return String[]authName1;//Shows error
    }

}
```

*[Note: Of course I am going to call all these method in my main class. I just haven't posted it here.]*

Comment: If you want a `single method` to return multiple values.. Then make the method type an `Array` and then store those multiple values in that `array` object return that..

Comment: Please look up "Objects", it might help you group your values together.

Comment: Sharp edge, have no idea how to make the method type an array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shoul change your code as shown below:

```
public class Book
{
    private String name;

    private String isbn;

    private String[] authors;

    /* constructor */

    public Book(String name, String isbn, String[] authors) {
        this.name = name;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.authors = authors;
    }

    /* setter */

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public void setAuthors(String[] authors) {
        this.authors = authors;
    }

    /* getter */

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public String[] getAuthors() {
        return authors;
    }
}



public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book book1 = new Book(
            "The brief history of time",
            "111",
            new String[]{"S. Hawking", " Hawking's friend"}
        );
        Book book2 = new Book(
            "100 years of solitude",
            "222",
            new String[]{"G. Marquez", "Marquezs friend"}
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats waht i wanted. it answers my question completely.

Comment: Unfortunately I discovered that it doesn't work. No results or value is printed out although I called each method with each book object.

Comment: What do you mean with "No results or value is printed out"? If you want to print an attribute you have to use one of the getter functions together with the `println()` method.

In `main` function, after the two books declaration, simply write `System.out.println(book1.getName());` if you want to print out the name of the first book, or `System.out.println(book2.getIsbn());` if you are interested in isbn code of book 2, and so on..

Comment: Sorry Sorry! never mind for my previous comment, ignore it. I just figured it out after a while. it's fine and working. Actually I forgot the way to print the attributes of object. I was a bit stressed too.

Comment: Don't warry, the most important thing is that you have find what you were looking for.

Answer (score 9):

You should create a Book class that contains the 3 properties, and your getter would return a Book instance.

Instead of

```
String name1 = "The brief history of time";
String isbn1 = "111";
String[] authName1 = {"S. Hawking", " Hawking's friend"};
```

You'll have

```
Book book1 = new Book ("The brief history of time", "111", {"S. Hawking", " Hawking's friend"});
```

Then :

```
public Book getBook1() {
    return book1;
}
```

You can further improve your `BooksObject` by having a books array (`Book[]`) instead of a different variable for each Book. Then you wouldn't need a separate `getBooki` method for each book.